# How to connect the paintComponent method to the JButton to draw a Rectangle or Oval?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener, paintcomponent

This issue I'm having is trying to allow user to choose from the GUI Combobox drop down #1 box (Choose Oval or Rectangle), #2 box (Filled or Hollow), #3 box (choose a color: Black, Blue, Yellow or Grey). Textfield #1 user can enter the Height, TextField #2 user can enter the Width, Textfield #3 user can enter x-coordinate and TextField #4 user can enter the y-coordinate. Draw button to call the paintComponent method to all the users to choose what they want to make, either Oval or Rectangle so it can be displayed on the Panel.

```
public class Drawing extends JPanel{

    public int currentShape;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        int x1 = 0;  
        int y1 = 0;
        g.drawRect(x1, y1, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.getColor();
        g.fillRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());


        //g.drawOval(x, y, width, height);
        g.getColor();
        g.fillOval(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());


    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);

    }

    public void drawShape(int currentShape) throws OutsideBounds {

    }

}
```

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Project3 {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField widthTextField;
    private JTextField heightTextField;
    private JTextField xCoordinateTextField;
    private JTextField yCoordinateTextField;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Project3 window = new Project3();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Project3() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Geometric Drawing");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 536, 373);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        JLabel lblShapeType = new JLabel("Shape Type");

        JLabel lblFillType = new JLabel("Fill Type");

        JLabel lblColor = new JLabel("Color");

        JLabel lblWidth = new JLabel("Width");

        JLabel lblHeight = new JLabel("Height");

        JLabel lblXCoordinate = new JLabel("x coordinate");

        JLabel lblYCoordinate = new JLabel("y coordinate");


        //String[] shapeString = { "Oval", "Rectangle"};
        JComboBox<String> shapeTypeComboBox = new JComboBox<String>();
        //Drawing oval = (Drawing) shapeTypeComboBox.getSelectedItem();

        shapeTypeComboBox.addItem("Oval");
        shapeTypeComboBox.addItem("Rectangle");


        JComboBox<String> fillTypeComboBox = new JComboBox<String>();
        fillTypeComboBox.addItem("Solid");
        fillTypeComboBox.addItem("Hollow");

        JComboBox<String> colorComboBox = new JComboBox<String>();
        colorComboBox.addItem("Black");
        colorComboBox.addItem("Red");
        colorComboBox.addItem("Orange");
        colorComboBox.addItem("Yellow");
        colorComboBox.addItem("Green");
        colorComboBox.addItem("Blue");
        colorComboBox.addItem("Magenta");

        widthTextField = new JTextField();
        widthTextField.setColumns(10);

        heightTextField = new JTextField();
        heightTextField.setColumns(10);

        xCoordinateTextField = new JTextField();
        xCoordinateTextField.setColumns(10);

        yCoordinateTextField = new JTextField();
        yCoordinateTextField.setColumns(10);

        JPanel drawPanel = new JPanel();
        TitledBorder titled = new TitledBorder("Shape Drawing");
        drawPanel.setBorder(titled);

        JButton btnDraw = new JButton("Draw");
        btnDraw.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }


        });
```

Comment: See the duplicate please, but the bottom line is that you can't do this directly but rather have to use some sort of *indirection* where in your button's ActionListener you change the state of a field in your class, perhaps a String (as in the example), a boolean, or (my choice) an enum, and then call `repaint()`. In the JPanel's paintComponent method, you use the state of that field to help decide what to draw.

Comment: That helped a little but it didnt show me how to change the color or how to add the choices to the combobox